# Issue with jquery animate with multiple divs (same class)

Tags: javascript, html, css, click, jquery-animate

I'm running an online-store and would like to spice up the product-listing a little bit. All I'm trying to do is to increase the height of a div when a user clicks on some text in that div.

My problem is that the div class exists several times on my site (for each product). So when I click, all the divs are increasing instead only the one I intend to.

Please let me know if this lacks in details or if further/better explanation is required.

Here's my code.

Thanks a lot for looking into it.
Daniel

```
{foreach name=aussen item=module_data from=$product_listing}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".box-wide-more").click(function() {
                $(".box-wide").animate({
                    height: '300px'
                }, 500);
            });
        });     
    </script>

        <div class="box-wide">
            <p class="box-wide-more">Read more</p>
        </div>

{/foreach}
```

Comment: why should the script be foreached? write it in $(document).ready(); event in a seperate js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy ;)

```
            $(this).closest(".box-wide").animate({
                height: '300px'
            }, 500);
```

why should the script be foreached? write it in $(document).ready(); event in a seperate js file

Comment: Wow... easy indeed. This helped me a lot. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of animating all the divs with class "box-wide", animate only the clicked objects parent

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8j4n6/

```
$(".box-wide-more").click(function() {


    var $this = $( this ), // The object that has been clicked ( ".box-wide-more" )
        parent = $this.parent(); // The objects direct parent

    parent.animate({
        height: '300px'
    }, 500);

});
```

Comment: closest() could arguably be better to use. This approach is easily understandable and works aswell.

Answer (score 0):

If there will be so many parent elements of `.box-wide-more` then to get a specific parent element (i.e. `.box-wide`), you can use below code.

```
  $(".box-wide-more").click(function() {    
    $(this).parents().find('.box-wide').animate({
        height: '300px'
    }, 500);
  });
```